# Draw rectangle with empty partial fill

Tags: android, draw, android-progressbar

Here's what I want to do: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZk9N.png)

I have a progressBar and I want to overlay this onto it so that I can achieve rounded corners. Problem is, if I use a 9patch image, it doesn't scale down, and scaling up pixelates the corners. Also, the corners when I increase the size of the progressBar, don't look sharp enough.

So I thought maybe drawing such a rectangle on top would make it 100% precise with crisp quality. Unfortunately, I've never used that before and there's no tutorial similar to what I want to achieve.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Have you tried an xml shape drawable?

Comment: if that means creating an xml and then using png/9patch images in that xml with tags, yes I have. That's what I'm using right now. It works great, I've achieved what I wanted to, however, since I'm using images, the corners aren't sharp enough since the progressbar is not more than a few pixels in height (22 px approx 4-8 dp)

Comment: I'll post an answer which might help you understand. Where you are now applying the 9patch, apply the shape drawable instead and see how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a shape drawable, you should be able to achieve what you want. You reference it just like any other drawable (android:src/android:background).

Let's name this file rounded_rect.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#80ffffff" />
</shape>
```

The radius can be more or less than 20dp, it will actually scale down if the container that it's drawn in requires less for the sides to be perfectly rounded; the color is white with a bit of transparency (#80).

Save it to your drawable folder and refer to it as you usually would with any png/jpg/etc drawable:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/rounded_rect" />
```

Comment: Thanks bud, I'll update ya on how that works very soon.

Comment: I tried out what you recommended. Also, the shape is perfect, very crisp. Now, is there a way to do an invert of that? I mean, we draw a rounded rectangle, but, can we draw an inverse rounded rectangle, so that it will remove that much area from a square and I would get something like the image shared in the main post?

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484776/android-9-patch-image-with-progressbar
This is what I'm trying to achieve.